# Una letra, seguida de un guión, y un número entre 1 y 999

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentado comprobar en java que en una cadena haya un patrón determinado, en este caso seria: letra-numero (cualquier letra seguida de un guión sin espacio y después del guión sin espacio un número ente el 1 y el 999). La letra es una letra en mayúsculas entre A y Z.

Este es mi código:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]&&-&&[0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(trans.getText().toString().trim());
if (!m.find())
{
    //Cadena Incorrecta
}
```

La cadena debe cumplir de principio a fin para ser válida.

Ejemplos: `A-66`, `B-998`, `C-2`.

Comment: @Mariano, el patron es valido cuando se cumple de principio a fin (ejemplos: A-66, B-998, C-2,...) y si letras de la A a la Z (mayúsuclas)  y números del 1 a 999

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una letra mayúscula, seguida de un guión y entre 1 y 3 dígitos:

```
regex = "^[A-Z]-\\d{1,3}$";
```

Descripción:

- `^` - coincide con el inicio del texto.
- `[A-Z]` - es una [clase de caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes) que coincide con un solo caracter (A a Z).
- `-` - coincide​ con un guión literal (cualquier caracter sin un [significado especial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs), se toma como literal).
- `\d{1,3}` - coincide con un [dígito](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) `[0-9]`, repetido por el [cuantificador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) entre 1 y 3 veces.

  > Lleva una sola `\`, pero en el código se usan 2 porque Java interpreta `"\\"` como una sola barra.
- `$` - coincide con el [fin del texto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds).

---

Aunque, si nos ponemos más estrictos, los dígitos de la expresión anterior también coinciden con `0`, `00` o `000`. Para que sea realmente entre 1 y 999, sin ceros a la izquierda:

```
regex = "^[A-Z]-[1-9]\\d{0,2}$";
```

- Si quisieras incluir otros caracteres además de A-Z, sólo basta agregarlos dentro de la clase. Por ejemplo, permitiendo tildes y Ñ: `[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]`

Más información en [*Regular Expressions Tutorial*](http://regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html).